# How to convert datetime.datetime to GMT format python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I am having an input as:

```
test_date = 2019-06-15 10:16:55-06:00
```

the code to convert is:

```
new_value= datetime.strptime(test_date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
```

After getting the value from new_value> I need to convert it to:

```
new_date = new_value.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

But I am getting an error as below:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

When I try to convert test_date as string like str(test_date). It causes

```
 ValueError: time data '2019-06-15 10:16:55-06:00' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_value= test_date.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
new_date = datetime.strptime(new_value,'%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

new_date will give you the output.

Answer (score 2):

`%a` refers to weekday like Sun, Mon, ..., etc, but it does not appear in your `test_date` input. Therefore it raises an error. `-06:00` means Central Standard Time, e.g. in United states, Chicago. Try the following instead.

```
from datetime import datetime

test_date = '2019-06-15 10:16:55-06:00'
new_value = datetime.strptime(test_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
new_value = new_value.timestamp()
new_value = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(new_value) #change from CST to GMT
new_date = new_value.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
print(new_date)
```

06/15/2019 04:16:55 PM

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify you date format at `strptime` to parse date correctly.

Then you need to convert date to GMT timezone like this

```
from datetime import datetime

test_date = '2019-06-15 10:16:55-06:00'
new_value = datetime.strptime(test_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
new_value_timestamp = new_value.timestamp()
gmt_date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(new_value_timestamp)
new_date = gmt_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
print(new_date)
```

Output

```
06/15/2019 04:16:55 PM
```

Comment: Unix time is a  detour here, you have `astimezone`...

Answer (score 1):

```
    from datetime import datetime

    date_string = "21-June-2018"
    date_string1 = "2019-06-21 10:16:55-0600"

    print("date_string =", date_string)
    print("type of date_string =", type(date_string))

    date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d-%B-%Y")
    date_object1 = datetime.strptime(date_string1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")

    print("date_object =", date_object)
    print("date_object1 =", date_object1)
    print("type of date_object =", type(date_object))
```